# Adding custom error message once Exception called within a loop

Tags: php, exception, yii, yii-components

I have the following block of code within a while loop (while loop generated from a csv) - if for whatever something goes wrong then ALL transactions are rolled back. This seems to work fine, i'd like to be able to 'log' each row/iteration within this loop where an Exception takes place to enable to display a flash message that will say something like the following below.. is this possible?

```
"You have a problem on Line 12."
"You have a problem on Line 17."
```

Transaction Code

```
try {
  if ($model->save()) {
      // continue with whatever logic you have
      $transaction->commit();
  }else{
      throw new Exception('Could not save model');
  }
}catch(Exception $e){
   $transaction->rollback();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always use `addError()` function of models to add a custom message to and attribute, and after that something went wrong, you can check the model for error messages with `getErrors()`.